# What is the absolute cheapest accommodation in Kuwait (besides couch surfing)?

Tags: budget, accommodation, kuwait

I hear that food and some other things are very cheap in Kuwait but that accommodation is "expensive".

Unfortunately the usual sources, such as Wikitravel don't say how much money "expensive" is.

Also I know there are many guest workers in Kuwait from much poorer countries, including the Philippines.

So what prices am I looking at for the cheapest places to crash? Are there hostels? Are there places to camp in a tent? Are there cheap hotels or something else intended for guest workers but where backpackers would also be able to stay?

I'm interested both for the entire country and for the capital, Kuwait City.

Comment: A similar question asked a year later: [How cheap are the cheapest accommodations in Saudi Arabia?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22982)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 5 HI hostels in Kuwait, including one in Kuwait City:

http://www.hihostels.com/guide/HI-Hostels-Guide-Kuwait.pdf

Apparently the price for HI members is 3 KD/night, or around US$10.  Not too shabby.

Guest workers almost always stay in company dormitories, which don't cater to random travellers.  And you'd probably want to avoid them anyway unless sleeping in a tin shed with 50 people and no air con in 50+ degree temps sounds like your idea of a good time...

Comment: +1 for this. I tried hostelbookers and booking.com, my go-to sites, and couldn't beat US$90 on them!

Comment: Wow surprising then that WikiTravel doesn't mention them when it's so easy (-:

Comment: It's a wiki, go fix it! ;)

Comment: Yeah but it's commercial, taking our help for free and making money off it so I don't feel like it d-;

Comment: So, what are you doing on StackExchange.com then?  This is a commercial site as well, with the same content license (CC by-sa) as Wikitravel!

Comment: StackExchange was honest with us from the beginning. Wikitravel's people (not public faces like Jeff and Joel) pulled the rug out from under its volunteers after three years once they got greedy and saw an opportunity to  monetize. At this point some volunteers objected and forked [WikiVoyage](http://www.wikivoyage.org/). I do contribute to Wikitravel, just not as freely or as happily as I do here. Anyway, it looks like CC by by-sa was only introduced a couple of years ago so that's a good move I wasn't aware of!

Comment: We're getting way off-topic here, but Wikitravel's been CC by-sa from day one, so the content is, has always been and will remain free.  But there's some interesting developments happening in Wikiland that I suspect you'll like, so stay tuned...